# msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail temp table does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, temporary-tables, database-mail

I have created a temp table and would like to email the results I am getting the following error.

> Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server
>   PRODYCHDBX3\X3V7, Line 1 Invalid object name '#WODups'.

After the temp table is created I ran the following code.

```
 DECLARE             @recordcount INT
 SELECT @recordcount = ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) 
 FROM #WODups

 IF (@recordcount > 0)

 BEGIN

 SELECT * FROM #WODups
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 @profile_name = 'SQL Mail',
 @recipients = 'jXXn.XXXn??@yXXXXXX.com;XXXXXXXX1@gmail.com',           
 @query = 'SELECT FROM #WODups',

 @subject = 'Duplicate Work Order Production Tracking',
 --@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
 @body =0;

 DROP TABLE #WODups
```

Why am I getting this error, and how may I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [scott-hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) in comments:

> You can't access local temp tables using dbmail.  At a minimum, it
>   would have to be a global (double ##) table.  Even global tables can
>   be a problem due to locking/blocking due to the fact the dbmail runs
>   in a separate process than the process that creates the temp tables.
>
> Table variables are not visible to the dbmail process either.
>
> One option that I have used is to declare a cursor over the local temp
>   table, fetch each row and 'build' the body of the email instead of
>   trying to 'attach' a file.  It depends on how much data you're
>   extracting.  Formatting can be a little tricky.  After the body has
>   been built, simply invoke the send_dbmail stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I email results (and it's not 100K rows or whatever) I like to mark it up with CSS and send it as HTML so it is readable. [Shnugo has a great function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml/39487565#39487565) for doing this over on Stackoverflow.

To use it, aside from his instructions, you can do something like so:

```
declare @body xml = 
    (select dbo.ufn_CreateHTMLTable (
        (SELECT FROM #WODups
         for xml path ('row'),elements xsinil)
    ,null,null,null))

--Maybe add some borders, Shnugo shows how to do it with his funciton too

declare @body_html varchar(max)
set @body_html =  
    '<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
    .center
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    table,th
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table,tr
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    table,td
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>' 
    + cast(@body as varchar(max))

    exec msdb..sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SQL Mail', 
    ,@recipients = 'someone@domain.com'
    ,@subject = 'This is my Subject'
    ,@body = @body_html
    ,@body_format = 'HTML'
```